# Is it possible to temporarily alter an instance variable for a chained method call?

Tags: ruby

I have a class that lazily loads data from a database into an instance variable, they are events in an array in numeric order. The class has several methods that analyse this array, here is an example of how I use it.

```
class Foo
  def initialize
    @a = [1,2,3,4,5] # data from database
  end

  def analyse
    @a.reduce(:+)
  end
end

d = Foo.new
result = d.analyse
```

I wanted to be able to apply these methods to the data after a very basic filter (eg: `<= 3`) and I imagined being able to call it like so:

```
d.at(3).analyse
```

and that the `at` method only affected the instance variable for the chained `analyse` call. i.e.

```
d = Foo.new # data loaded into instance var [1,2,3,4,5]
d.analyse # 15
d.at(3).analyse # 6
d.analyse # 15
```

I'm not sure how I can do this without re-creating a completely new object within the at call and this feels inefficient. I have a work around which would change how I call the `at` method - not the end of the world but I wondered if what I want is feasible whilst remaining efficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm not sure how I can do this without re-creating a completely new object within the at call and this feels inefficient.

I don't think creating a new object is too expensive. You could return a new `Foo` from `at`, initialized with a subset of the original data. You'd have another `Foo` instance and another `Array` instance, but the array would contain the very same objects:

```
class Foo
  def initialize(a = nil)
    @a = a || [1,2,3,4,5] # use a or fetch data from database
  end

  def analyse
    @a.reduce(:+)
  end

  def at(max)
    Foo.new(@a.take_while { |x| x <= max })
  end
end
```

Example:

```
d = Foo.new
d.analyse #=> 15
d.at(3).analyse #=> 6
d.analyse #=> 15
```

Comment: I think "_but the array would contain the very same objects_" was what I needed to hear.

Answer (score 0):

You can prepare another instance variable which is set by `at`, overrides `@a` when defined, and is reset by `analyse`.

```
class Foo
  def initialize
    @a = [1,2,3,4,5]
  end
  def at i
    @b = @a.select{|e| e <= i}
    self
  end
  def array
    if instance_variable_defined?(:@b)
      @b.tap{remove_instance_variable(:@b)}
    else
      @a
    end
  end
  def analyse
    array.reduce(:+)
  end
end
```